# Replicating excel data table

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to replicate a data table (excel) that looks something similar to this:

```
Model        | Deployed | Depot | Total
---------------------------------------
HP 640 G1         7         4       11
HP 6360 Thin      20        2       22
HP 6470 B         15        0       15
---------------------------------------
     Totals: |    42        6       48
```

The data model for my `inventory` collection:

```
inventory = {
    deployed: {
        date: null,
        office: null,
        status: "depot",
        user: null
    }
    history: Array[0]
    make: "HP"
    model: "HP 640 G1"
    recieved: "2014-08-08T15:00:43-04:00"
    removed: false
    tag: "0013"
    type: "Desk Phone"  
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the helpers for this to create the data table above.

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {{#each ?}}
            <td>{{ ? }}</td> // make
            <td>{{ ? }}</td> // deployed
            <td>{{ ? }}</td> // depot
            <td>{{ ? }}</td> // total
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Totals:</td>
            <td>{{ ? }}</td>
            <td>{{ ? }}</td>
            <td>{{ ? }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Any direction helps right now. Thanks.

Comment: A little more info would be helpful. How do you calculate the "deployed" and "depot" columns? I'm guessing something like: group all inventory by model, then count all of them with a "deployed" key and a "deployed.location" == depot?

Comment: My data model is a little messed up I guess. Location and Status are pretty much the same thing. Status should be either, Deployed or Depot. I'm removing location.

Comment: @DavidWeldon What information can I give you?

Comment: Did you have a look at packages like [reactive-table](https://atmospherejs.com/package/reactive-table) that can abstract out html construction burdens?

Comment: No I haven't @SerkanDurusoy, but I will give it a try. Thanks!